# It is possible to get path of videos added from iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, ios6

I want to get path of videos that are stored in the iPhone Videos app, as shown (not in the camera roll).

[image]

Example : I have added 2 or 3 video to my iPhone from iTunes, and now I want to play that video in an app, so I'll need to get the path of all the videos that are on the iPhone in order to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MPMediaPropertyPredicate** *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MPMediaTypeMovie] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[query addFilterPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *items = [query items];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]init];
for (MPMediaItem* item in items)
{
    //get the Title of video
    NSString* title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
     NSLog(@"title %@",title);

    //get the path of Video
     url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    NSLog(@"url %@",url);
}
```